# What is the meaning of server in different frameworks and languages?

Tags: node.js, tomcat, jetty, dropwizard

I have a very basic question. When I write REST services, there is a server on which your service runs. When I write my service in Java using dropwizard framework, it uses Jetty server to expose endpoints. But what is actually this server? Because server is just a machine on which we host. For example, in node js application, when we just write a createServer(), it creates the server locally on the machine. Does it also have some fancy names like Jetty or Tomcat that it uses internally? I am little confused, what exactly is meant by Jetty, Tomcat, etc? Are these some library which makes it easy to connect to the machine OS and all or its something else.

My question looks very dumb but I wanted to understand the concept of servers.

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. `createServer()` doesn't create a machine.

Comment: @EJP Yeah I know, it does not. But it must be using some server like Jetty or Tomcat, right.

Comment: A server can be hardware or software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit confusing, you're right, as *server* can mean the machine itself, or the software that actually creates the web server.

But software needs some hardware to run, isn't it ?

*Server* usually means **the combination of both**.

Node.js servers have also some fancy names like [Express](http://expressjs.com), or [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/), and many others that make setting up your app easier.

This is more about the context of the discussion than frameworks and languages.